# Android. Разбиение контента по страницам

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка

Здравствуйте, я делаю  приложение - читалку для электронных книг. Книга будет в собственном формате, но это не важно. Книга может содержать изображения и текст. В приложении должна быть возможность увеличения текста, поэтому я не знаю сколько контента поместится на странице. Как узнать количество страниц, требуемых для размещения текста и картинок?

P. S. Если вопрос не понятен посмотрите, пожалуйста, приложение Amazon Kindle. Там при увеличении текста программа сразу же пересчитывает количество страниц.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения размера текста используется класс `Paint`, точнее его метод `measureText` или `getTextBounds`. Из `TextView` используемый `Paint` получается методом `getPaint`.

Размеры `View` - страницы получаются методами `getMeasuredWidth` и `getMeasuredHeight`.
Соответственно для рассчета количества страниц нужно найти высоту всего текста, который нужно отобразить + высоту всех картинок.

Картинки тоже масштабируются относительно размера экрана. Через `BitmapFactory` и методы `decode...`, принимающие объект `BitmapFactory.Options` можно получить размеры картинок не декодируя их в память - объекту `Options` нужно выставить флаг `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true`.

Таким образом получаешь все необходимые размеры, а далее уже зависит от того, как текст отображается, какие отступы, какие параграфы, сколько самого текста в книге - если там мегабайт 20 текста, то сразу весь текст в память лучше не загружать, а рассчитывать размеры кусками по мегабайту, например, или другими подходами. Ну и еще зависит от того, как рисуешь - корневой `RelativeLayout` и в нем `TextView` и `ImageView`, или кастомый `View`, а отрисовка идет в `onDraw`. Или может еще как.